# Min and max eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given matrix $A \in R^{n \times m}$.

Prove, that $\|A - \vec{x}\vec{y}^T\|_F^2$

($\vec{x} \in R^n, \vec{y} \in R^m$)

get minimum, when $\vec{x}$ is eigenvector of $AA^T$ matrix, eq to max eigenvalue, and $\vec{y}$ is eigenvector of $A^TA$ matrix,  eq min eigenvalue.

I think use identity $\|B\|_F^2 = \sum_{ij}b_{ij}^2 = tr(B^TB)$.

But I don't have ideas how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write the Frobenius norm, we obtain (after some calculations, ask if they are not clear) that this norm is equal to $$tr (A^TA)-2x^TAy+\|x\|^2\|y\|^2.$$
For a fixed $x$ this minimisation problem has a solution $y=\frac{A^Tx}{\|x\|^2}$, hence now we minimise with respect to $x$ the expression

$$tr (A^TA)-2x^TA\frac{A^Tx}{\|x\|^2} +\|x\|^2\left\|\frac{A^Tx}{\|x\|^2}\right\|^2=tr(A^TA)-\frac{\|A^Tx\|^2}{\|x\|^2}.$$

This expression, has its minimum when $x$ is the eigenvector with respect to maximal eigenvalue of $AA^T$. Easy to see now that the formula for $y$ implies that $y$ is an eigenvector for $A^TA$.